# Correct previous commit before commiting new changes

Tags: git

I have a simple question, but I couldn't find a duplicate here.

I committed changes *(commit 1)* to a `wip` branch and continued on with the development. Now I want to commit new changes *(commit 2)*, but I noticed that *commit 1* had a mistake.

How can I save my changes (relative to *commit 2*) without commiting them, go back to *commit 1* and fix it, then bring back those changes and execute *commit 2*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I have an understanding that you want to add more changes to commit 1.

`git stash` the changes that you did for commit-2  Then amend the previous commit.

For that You should use `git commit --amend`. It is described here:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/

Then You can apply the stashed changes using `git stash apply`

And commit the changes in commit -2

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing):

> Often, when you’ve been working on part of your project, things are in
>   a messy state and you want to switch branches for a bit to work on
>   something else. The problem is, you don’t want to do a commit of
>   half-done work just so you can get back to this point later. The
>   answer to this issue is the `git stash` command.

What you should do:

```
git stash
<checkout other branch>
<commit changes>
<checkout first branch>
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. stash your working state and fix *commit 1* with `commit --amend`, or
2. just commit you changes in the natural order and rebase afterwards. This will give something like

   ```
   commit1 -> commit2 -> commit1fix <HEAD
   ```

   and running `rebase -i HEAD~3`, you can reorder the commits like so:

   ```
   pick aaaa commit1
   fixup cccc commit1fix
   pick bbbb commit2
   ```